# Angularjs ng-value sum fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-value

Hi i have inputs like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="tbl.Public">
<input type="text" ng-model="tbl.Private">
<input type="text" ng-value="tbl.Public--tbl.Private" ng-model="tbl.Total">
```

the above form will working fine it will sum the Public and Private value  and put it in tbl.Total field. My problem is in edit form where value of **tbl.Total, tbl.Public, tbl.Private** are assign from database.

js

```
$scope.tbl.Public=10;
$scope.tbl.Private=25;
$scope.tbl.Total=35;
```

now after assigning a value from js when i change value of tbl.Public or tbl.Private in form it is not affecting a tbl.Total it should sum the two value and put it in tbl.Total field. 
Thank you for your any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) is usually used on radiobuttons and option elements, it's not a good fit for your use case.

A better thing to do would be implementing an `updateTotal()` function combined with [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). I would also recommend changing your `input` types to `number` so you're not allowing users to sum text.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="tbl.Public" ng-change="updateTotal();">
<input type="number" ng-model="tbl.Private" ng-change="updateTotal();">
<input type="number" ng-model="tbl.Total">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.updateTotal = function() {
  $scope.tbl.Total = $scope.tbl.Public + $scope.tbl.Private;
}
```

Comment: yes i know, i can solve in this way but just wondering if there is any solution for my code

Comment: @sanu If you can solve it this way, why do you want to use `ng-value` then? What's the advantage?

Comment: actually I have multiple sum fields in my form (more than 10), so If I do in my style I don't have to add extra functions in my js that is only the reason thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this to prevent from concatenate

```
$scope.updateTotal = function() { 
  var Public = Number($scope.tbl.Public || 0); 
  var Private = Number($scope.tbl.Private || 0); 
  $scope.tbl.Total = Public + Private; 
}
```